# Language R: Variable doesn't change inside a 'for()' cycle?

Tags: r, variables, error-handling

I am trying to analyze the value of "edoActual", but it doesn't seem to change its value after the for cycle.

When running it in RGui, it doesn't point any errors or warnings. When running it on RStudio it goes nuts. Either way it doesn't work.

```
edoActual = "q0";
print("Input cadena: ");
cadena <- scan("", what="char");

for(i in 1:length(cadena)) {
  if( edoActual == "q0" && cadena[i] == "a" ) {
    edoActual = "q1";
  }
  if( edoActual == "q0" && cadena[i] == "b" ) { 
    edoActual = "q0";
  }
  if( edoActual == "q1" && cadena[i] == "a" ) {
    edoActual = "q0";
  }
  if( edoActual == "q1" && cadena[i] == "b" ) {
    edoActual = "q1";
  }
  if( cadena[i] != "a" && cadena[i] != "b") {
    print("Error: invalid.");
    break;
  }  
}

if( i == length(cadena) ) {
  if(edoActual == "q1") {print("accepted (:");}
  if(edoActual == "q0") {print("rejected ):");}
}
```

What is supposed to happen:

```
[1] "Input cadena: "
1: a
2: a
3: b
4: a
5:
Read 4 ítems

[1] "accepted (:"
```

Comment: Did you mean to have else/if statements in there? Because on the first loop `edoActual=="q0"` and `cadena[1]=="a"` so you change to "q1" but then two if's later now `edoActual=="q1"` but still `cadena[1]=="a"` so you end up changing it back to "q0". Your value is changing in the loop, but you are just always changing it back to the same thing. Your logic just seems a bit off here.

Comment: Heck, that was it. Thanks man, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is actually changing too much because you are testing all the if statements every iteration.

So each time cadena[i] == 'a' the first if assigns 'q1' to edoActual and then when it reaches the 3rd if it becomes 'q0' again.

I think what you really want is testing only the first valid if statement. So when edoActual changes its value it proceeds to the next iteration. You can do this using else, it garantees that you go through the next test only if the previous one was False.

```
edoActual = "q0";
print("Input cadena: ");
cadena <- scan("", what="char");

for(i in 1:length(cadena)) {
  if( edoActual == "q0" && cadena[i] == "a" ) {
    edoActual = "q1";
  } else if( edoActual == "q0" && cadena[i] == "b" ) { 
    edoActual = "q0";
  } else  if( edoActual == "q1" && cadena[i] == "a" ) {
    edoActual = "q0";
  } else  if( edoActual == "q1" && cadena[i] == "b" ) {
    edoActual = "q1";
  } else if( cadena[i] != "a" && cadena[i] != "b") {
    print("Error: invalid.");
    break;
  }  
}

if( i == length(cadena) ) {
  if(edoActual == "q1") {print("accepted (:");}
  if(edoActual == "q0") {print("rejected ):");}
}
```